# Access to the source code of a framework and edit it

Tags: swift, frameworks

I'm using a framework based on objective-c, it has some limitations and issues, trying to find a way to edit its source code, but there is only a folder for header files, and the resource folder is also empty. In this case, I should open OWT file, am I right?

[image]

Comment: Is your framework coming from a repository like GitHub ?

Comment: Yes, but it's built from a repository, not the the direct use
https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-client-native

Comment: If you view code on GitHub you can see the source. Then you could download all source tree and build it (then update for your needs) on your computer